# Is there R syntax to delete rows with specific, multiple NAs in columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, na, delete-row

Hello coding community,

If my data frame looks like:

```
ID     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
Per1   1    2    3    4
Per2   2    NA   NA   NA
Per3   NA   NA   5    NA
```

Is there any syntax to delete the row associated with ID = Per2, on the basis that Col2, Col3, AND Col4 = NA? I am hoping for code that will allow me to delete a row on the basis that three specific columns (Col2, Col3, and Col4) ALL are NA. This code would NOT delete the row ID = Per3, even though there are three NAs.

Please note that I know how to delete a specific row, but my data frame is big so I do not want to manually sort through all rows/columns.

Big thanks!

Comment: longer and naive solution with base r `df[!is.na(df$Col2) | !is.na(df$Col3) | !is.na(df$Col3),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test for NA and delete rows with a number of NA's equal to the number of columns tested using `rowSums`.

```
dat[!rowSums(is.na(dat[c('Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4')])) == 3, ]
#     ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
# 1 Per1    1    2    3    4
# 3 Per3   NA   NA    5   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if_all`

```r
library(dplyr)
filter(df, !if_all(c(Col2, Col3, Col4), ~ is.na(.)))

#     ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
# 1 Per1    1    2    3    4
# 2 Per3   NA   NA    5   NA
```

**data**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c("Per1", "Per2", "Per3"), Col1 = c(1L, 2L, 
NA), Col2 = c(2L, NA, NA), Col3 = c(3L, NA, 5L), Col4 = c(4L, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I am receiving the error: "Input `..1$ID` must be a logical vector, not a character". Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Which data are you using? You should not get an error without the data I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Using `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(Col2:Col4, complete.cases))
    ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1 Per1    1    2    3    4
2 Per3   NA   NA    5   NA
```